# Basic question about logic

Tags: logic

If P implies Q, what can one say about the truth of not P implies not Q?

**Note**: I've revised the statement above. Sorry.

I'll also provide some context. I am considering the following statement on English Language and Usage Stack Exchange:

> Violation of rights triggers war. Prevention of violation of rights
>   prevents war.

Please correct me if I'm mistaken, but this statement seems to have the form:

> P implies Q. Not P implies not Q.

What can one say in general about the truth of not P implies not Q? I assume nothing, but I would appreciate an explanation/example.

Also, is "not P implies not Q" perhaps an example of a tautology in the sense that all wars involve the violation of rights, so if one can prevent the violation of rights, one can prevent all wars? The second part of this question seems like the contrapositive of the first part.

Comment: Not Q implies not P.

Comment: not p implies not q is no more a tautology than p implies q is.  After all, p implies q = not (-p) implies not (-q).  In your case you have agression => war as a statement.  Than you have the unstated but assumed statement war => aggression.  That mean agression = war and of course p => p (or -p=>-p) is a tautology.

Comment: Those statements violation triggers war and prevent prevents war are not precise logic.  Violation of rights triggers war does not mean violation => war.  Violations don't always mean war.  Just that it makes war more likely.  Nor does prevention mean wars never happen.  This makes sense a makes b likely => -a makes b less likely.  But in NO way does a imply b => -a imply -b.  That is simply NOT valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a statement $P \rightarrow Q$, you are asking about what we can deduce of $\lnot P  \rightarrow \lnot Q$.

Your intuition is correct in that one can say nothing about $\lnot P  \rightarrow \lnot Q$. Here are a few examples:

**Example 1:**

If it is raining, then it is cloudy outside .

From this, you cannot conclude that if it is not raining, then it is not cloudy (it might be cloudy outside but not raining for ex.)

**Example 2:**
If you are a human, then you have two legs.

From this, you can't conclude that if you're not a human, then you don't have two legs. What about monkeys and kangaroos etc.

**Example 3:**
If you are not alive, then you are dead

From this you actually can conclude that if you are not not alive (i.e. alive), then you are not dead. In this case, the statement $P \rightarrow Q$ should actually be $P \iff Q$.

---

A lot of English statements get fudged up when converted to logic. The statement:

> Violation of rights triggers war. Prevention of violation of rights prevents war.

is more like saying $P \iff Q$ which is kind of dodgy because it is saying a war is caused by violation of rights and nothing else. That is, if rights are not violated, then a war will always be prevented. You can take that as you will, but as the statement stands, a biconditional is probably closer to what it means and so yes, the statement is of the form $P \rightarrow Q$ and $\lnot P \rightarrow \lnot Q$ (which is equivalent to $P \iff Q$.

Comment: Great examples. I was thinking of one along the lines of legs, but more contrived than yours. One more question: I don't think it would be correct to preface the second sentence in my example ("Prevention of violation of rights prevents war.") with *Conversely* because the second sentence is not the converse of the first. Is there a word, analogous to *conversely*, for *not P implies not Q*? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @RichardKayser That is a good question. The converse is the correct word for `not P implies not Q` even though this might not be immediately obvious. The first thing to understand (call this *) is, from the statement  $P \rightarrow Q$, you can always deduce $\lnot Q \rightarrow \lnot P$ (they are logically equivalent statements). Now consider the converse of $P \rightarrow Q$ which would be $Q \rightarrow P$. From our principle *, we know $Q \rightarrow P$ is logically equivalent to $\lnot P \rightarrow \lnot Q$. Thus $\lnot P \rightarrow \lnot Q$ is actually the converse of $P \rightarrow Q$

Comment: I hope that makes sense but I may have misunderstood what you were asking. Please feel free to ask as many clarifying questions as you would like; this stuff is really unintuitive sometimes :)

Comment: I get it. It's been quite a while since I've done logic. I can see now how basic it is. Your help is much appreciated. No more questions. Tonight anyway. :-)

Answer (score 1):

> > Violation of rights triggers war. Prevention of violation of rights prevents war.
>
> Please correct me if I'm mistaken, but this statement seems to have the form:
>
> > P implies Q. Not P implies not Q.

You are correct.   However, the argument is not sound.    We can make the statements equivalent by correcting the direction of the conditional connectives.

> > Violation of rights *are sufficient to* trigger war.   Prevention of violations of rights *is necessary to* prevent war.
> >
> > $$(P\to Q) ~~\iff~~ (\neg P\gets \neg Q)$$

There are, after all, other things that trigger wars, so preventing violation of rights *alone* will not guaranteed war is prevented.   But if you wish to prevent war you will need to prevent violations among other things.

Comment: Good answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In colloquial English

Violation of rights trigger wars

Ergo

Maintaining rights prevents wars

does have the form P implies Q therefore not P implies Q.

And this is simply not valid logic as everyone else has pointed out.

However colloquially translating

Violation of rights trigger wars

as P implies Q is not quite accurate.  It isn't "if P then Q" (always; no exception).  It's more "higher incidence of P => higher probability of Q".

In which case "higher incidence of not P => higher probability of not Q" *is* a valid inference.

But "high prob P => high prob Q" which can be an English interpretation of "implies", is most certainly not the mathematical interpretation of "implies".

Comment: Enlightening from language point of view. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$Q$ might be a *tautology* - that is, always true. Then $P$ implies $Q$ *and* $\neg P$ implies $Q$ - indeed, *everything* implies $Q$! So you can't conclude anything like what you want.

What we can conclude from $P\implies Q$ is $\neg Q\implies \neg P$ - this is the *contrapositive*. Think about it this way: supposing $P\implies Q$, if $Q$ is *false* then $P$ can't be *true*, since if $P$ were true then $Q$ would be true. (This goes the other way, too - $P\implies Q$ is *equivalent to* $Q\implies P$.)

Comment: I apologize. I edited my question and tried to provide some context. I took your point regarding the possibility of a tautology, albeit not a mathematical tautology. (I am familiar with contrapositives.)

Answer (score 0):

This no necesary is true. Results equivalent are a example of this. 
If P imply Q, is true that not Q imply not P.
If "k even then 2k is even" and  "if k is odd then 2k is even".